# DXL error not undestood :DXL: <D:\XXXX.dxl:1234> Un module en cours est requis pour lopération => US traduction = operation requires a current module

Tags: ibm-doors

I have following error message :
DEBUG: isBaseline(spec_produit) = true -R-E- DXL: <D:\XXXX.dxl:1234> Un module en cours est requis pour lopération
US traduction = operation requires a current module

line 1234 is the following : print "DEBUG: baseline loaded for " name(module_in_database) " = " major(baseline_open) "." minor(baseline_open) suffix(baseline_open) "\n"

With : baseline_open = baselineInfo(module_in_database) (=true)

I don't understand why I have this message as I already use this kind of coding elsewhere with success.

Here I have the message in a loop that I use to detect if I have still open module after having close all open modules (I don't know why I still have open module but it is another subject)

the loop is :

```
 // display list of open module at then end of the script
    for module_in_database in database do 
    {   
        logResult = logResult "INFO: open modules at the end the script are " fullName(module_in_database) "\n"
        // display more information on open modules : (DEBUG) :
        print "DEBUG: isBaseline(" name(module_in_database) ") = " isBaseline(module_in_database) "\n"
        baseline_open =  baselineInfo(module_in_database)
        if (baseline_open != null) {
            print "DEBUG: baseline loaded for" name(module_in_database) " = " major(baseline_open) "." minor(baseline_open) suffix(baseline_open) "\n"
        } else {
            print "DEBUG: " name(module_in_database) " = CURRENT \n"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1:

```
Module module_in_database
Baseline baseline_open
string logResult = ""

// display list of open module at then end of the script
for module_in_database in database do 
{   
    logResult = logResult "INFO: open modules at the end the script are " fullName(module_in_database) "\n"
    if type (module_in_database) == "Formal" then {
        // display more information on open modules : (DEBUG) :
        print "DEBUG: isBaseline(" name(module_in_database) ") = " isBaseline(module_in_database) "\n"
        baseline_open =  baselineInfo(module_in_database)
        if (baseline_open != null) {
            current = module_in_database  // <------ set current module so that the next line works!
            print "DEBUG: baseline loaded for" name(module_in_database) " = " major(baseline_open) "." minor(baseline_open) suffix(baseline_open) "\n"
        } else {
            print "DEBUG: " name(module_in_database) " = CURRENT \n"
        }
    } else {
        print fullName(module_in_database) " is a Link Module. No baselineInfo available\n"
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
Module module_in_database
Baseline baseline_open
string logResult = ""
ModuleVersion mv
string version_string

// display list of open module at then end of the script
for module_in_database in database do 
{   
    logResult = logResult "INFO: open modules at the end the script are " fullName(module_in_database) "\n"
    if type (module_in_database) == "Formal" then {
        // display more information on open modules : (DEBUG) :
        print "DEBUG: isBaseline(" name(module_in_database) ") = " isBaseline(module_in_database) "\n"
        mv = moduleVersion (module_in_database)
        version_string = versionString (mv) // <---- don't use "major" and "minor", instead use version_string, which does not require a "current" module
        if (version_string != "") {
            print "DEBUG: baseline loaded for" name(module_in_database) " = " version_string "\n"
        } else {
            print "DEBUG: " name(module_in_database) " = CURRENT \n"
        }
    } else {
        print fullName(module_in_database) " is a Link Module. No baselineInfo available\n"
    }
}
```

P.S: Having read through our thread again, I think that the misunderstanding stems from DOORS' inconsistency when naming things. a "current version" is a Module which is not a baseline. A "current module" in DOORS-speak is a module version that is "the one '''module''' that the user currently interacts with". When you have opened five windows with modules (either current version or baselines or link modules), only one of these windows is at the front - only one of these windows catches your keyboard input - and that window contains the "current" Module. If you have a one-liner like `print fullName (current Module)` and you open the database explorer (main window), click on Tools->Edit DXL… and paste the code, it will complain that no Module is current. if you then click on one window and in this window click on Tools->Edit DXL…, you will get the SAME DXL window, but now the code will run, because now DOORS knows which Module is the one that you mean when you say `fullName (current Module)`.

Unfortunately, that's still not correctly said: the current Module is not directly related to the window at the front - you might even have opened Modules invisibly. And using DXL you can say "this invisible Module is the current one" although there is a window at the front showing a different Module.

It's complicated but I hope that I explained it correctly now.

Comment: Thanks it is clear. Method1 is working great. Method2 gives me a blank string for the version. about the current requirement for major/minor, etc I guess I never need it because I use this after a "load" and I guess that the load change the current module to the loaded module. right ?

Comment: If `versionString (mv)` is a blank string, that means that the code is looking at a current version. If it is looking at a baseline, the versionString should give sth like "2.1 Bugfix". I think it is correct that loading a baseline changes the current module to the baseline. But I would not rely on that - I prefer using ModuleVersions so that I don't have to rely on the rather fragile "current Module" (which might be changed to sth different than you expect e.g. by a post-open-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Strange.
I have been able to run the script  with the following declarations

```
Module module_in_database
Baseline baseline_open
string logResult = ""
```

and I got the expected results.
I remember some problems with perms that expect a current module even though they shouldn't.

Perhaps you just need to add some lines to your loop

```
if type (module_in_database) == "Formal" then {
    current = module_in_database 
} else {
    continue
}
```

but still, that should not be necessary

Comment: thanks, what is the "formal type" ? how do I use current in my loop ? I don't have to use it ?

Comment: There used to be three different module types, nowadays, you have the types "Link" and "Formal", the latter being "normal" modules (as in File -> New -> Formal Module).  You would use the snippet directly before or after your line `logResult = `. I am not really sure whether this helps at all, I just noticed that sometimes, some perms only work for the "current" module (the GUI equivalent would be to double click on a module in the database explorer when the module as already open). You see the difference If you run a small script like `print fullName current Module`

Comment: thanks I will check but I'm not sure it is the problem because when the script fail I have a display that indicate the name of the module and it was not a link module :/

Comment: Well, if line 1234 is the one with the debug message, then it says that at least one of the perms in that line, i.e. `string name (Module m)`, `string major (Baseline b)`, `string minor (Baseline b)`and `string suffix (Baseline b)` requires that a module is set as "current" (probably the latter three). So, yes, the indicated module is not a Link module but a Formal module, and my idea is to set exactly this module as "current", so that the perms have their prerequisites fulfilled.

Comment: which makes sense insofar as it is possible to create an object of type `Baseline` without any reference to any Module, e.g. by using the perm `Baseline nextMajor (string suff)`. So, a "Baseline" seems to be sth like an abstract object that only "makes sense" in combination with a concrete Module, i.e. the current Module.

Comment: I think I don't understand, baseline_info function is made to be used with a module. And not especially a current module. Then baseline_info provides the baseline and I should be able to display major, minor etc.

Comment: correct me, if I'm wrong, but I think that the error message does not complain about the line `baseline_open =  baselineInfo(module_in_database)`, but about two lines below, that with the print command. So, even if the object `baseline_open` of type 'Baseline' is set, it might still be that a print command relying on `baseline_open` might fail if a current Module is not set.

Comment: Ooo you mean that I may have problem because the baseline is open but not the current module of this baseline, right ? If yes what is the solution? I 've closed everything and I need to close these last file, it would be a shame to open again the current of this module to have information about these baseline. Don't you think ?

Comment: No. The loop `for Module in database` iterates over every module that is currently open, regardless of whether it is a baseline or a current module or a link module, whether it is open visibly or invisibly. But DOORS says that the command `major (Baseline)` only works when the corresponding module is set to "current". I'll post another answer with snippets that hopefully explains what I mean.

Comment: but major need to be used with a baseline, not on a current. I miss something I think.

Comment: I tried to explain the difference between "current version of a module" and "current module" in my other answer, see above. I hope that it becomes clear there, I don't know how to explain it in other words.

Comment: ok now I understand the difference between both current :) :) it's tricky. ok, I didn't know that major/minor function need the module to be the current module...